# What does Grails create-service do exactly?

Tags: grails, service

I am developing a Grails application (with Grails 1.3.7). In service layer, I did not use the command 'create-service' to create my service but do it manually.

As the result, my service was not auto initialize in controllers and other services, and it did not handle transaction.

But I do not know where is the differences from create service by command with by manual? Because I do not see any configuration file which figure out this? (I mean in traditional Spring, we always have some configuration files which specify all beans in applications, but in   Grails is not).

I want to fix this issue and commit to SVN server my fix, but I do not want to delete the old service and commit the new one which is created by Grails command. So could you please help me:
1. explain what is the differences from create service by command with by manual?
2. how to change the the service created by manual to service created by command without replacing the old one?
Thank you so much!

Comment: can you post the package and name of your service class, perhaps the code?  As a test can you create a testService using create-service and verify it behaves as a service in your project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> explain what is the differences from create service by command with by manual?

Assuming you put your service in `grails-app/services` and followed the naming convention using a postfix of `Service` The only difference is that you get a nice template that looks like

```
class SomeService {
    boolean transactional = true

    def someMethod() {
    }
}
```

and it automatically creates a unit test with the name `SomeServiceTests`. That is it. BTW transactional defaults to `true` if you do not include it.

> how to change the the service created by manual to service created by command without replacing the old one?

There is nothing to do assuming you followed the conventions. If you did follow the conventions and you are still experience problems please update your question with more details such as how are you trying to use your service and a example of your service.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you put your class in the `grails-app/services` directory, it should act just like any other service (and work as a spring bean).

If you put it in `src/java` or `src/groovy`, it's not considered a service (and not loaded as a service artefact by grails).  It could still be a spring bean, but you'd have to manually add it to the resources.groovy file.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am sure that I have put my service to the right place (grails-app/services) along with other services which are created by command. But I still have to initialize it whenever I invoke it on controllers, and it did not control transaction too.

Comment: you service class have to match <your service name>Serivce pattern, e.g. ExampleService. then you can inject the service into a controller by declaring def exampleService as a class member. as the previous poster mentioned it's very important that you create the groovy class file in the right dir.

Comment: @hitty5 +1 forgot about the requirement to name it with "Service" at the end when writing the answer.  You're correct, that is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that the Grails autowiring of the beans must be exact, so if you have MyService and you want to use it in the controller, make sure you have "def myService" or "MyService myService."  If you would prefer different names of your member variables, you can also use the Spring Autowired annotation directly, though I've only tried autowiring grails types (e.g. a grails service) autowired to a bean I declared in resources.xml

If you put services, or any other bean in the resources.xml or resources.groovy files, they will also be autowired intro controllers, other services, etc.

It's best to think of Grails as "rapid Spring", so the autowiring, transactions, etc all are backed by Spring configuration and such.